# Search pattern not terminated in Perl

Tags: perl

I've been trying to debug this search pattern not terminated error, but can't seem to find where in(I guess my for each loop)it is not terminated?  The last line at the bottom of my code is line 160.  Can anyone give me any hints on what in my code is wrong?  I am trying to print out each header in the select results and each of the data in each of its rows and print it out on the CGI page.

C:\xampp\cgi-bin>perl create_report.cgi
Search pattern not terminated at create_report.cgi line 160.

```
foreach $rpt_sel_output(@desc_origin)
{
($rptid, $servid, $rptcat_id, $desc, $remail_add, $remail_info, $ent_usr, $ent_dte, $up_usr, $up_dte, $fav)=split(",",$rpt_sel_output);
if($rptid eq 'ReportID') #header rows
{
print"<tr>/n";
print"<th>$rptid</th>";
print"<th>$servid</th>";
print"<th>$rptcat_id</th>";
print"<th>$desc</th>";
print"<th>$remail_add</th>";
print"<th>$remail_info</th>";
print"<th>$ent_usr</th>";
print"<th>$ent_dte</th>";
print"<th>$up_usr</th>";
print"<th>$up_dte</th>";
print"<th>$fav</th>";
print"<tr/>/n";
print"</table>/n";
next;
}
print"<tr>/n";# data from select that was outputed
print"<td>$rptid</td>";
print"<td align 'right'> $servid</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $rptcat_id</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $desc</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $remail_add</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $remail_info</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $ent_usr</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $ent_dte</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $up_usr</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $up_dte</td>/n";
print"<td align 'right'> $fav</td>/n";
print"<tr/>/n";
}
}
print"</table>/n";


print"<<FOOTER/n"; 
     </body>
print</html>FOOTER;
```

Comment: I think you intended `\n` for new line. `/n` has no special meaning. Also, what text editor do you use to edit perl code? Does it have [syntax highlighting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_highlighting) feature?

Comment: One more point, the last three lines of your code seem to be using [here doc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Perl). Refer the link to know how to fix your code.

Comment: Ok thanks guys..yes I am using notepad++ and gedit.  The editor doesn't really help at all for CGI scripting.  Nothing is highlighted for me its all black text :(  Do you have any recommended text editors?

Comment: It is a personal choice, however, you can manually set the language as perl to enable perl specific syntax highlighting in notepad++. Perhaps, it does not by itself understand .cgi extension. Gedit might have some similar setting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing double quotes around those print statements at the bottom.  They should look like this:

```
print"<<FOOTER/n"; 
print "</body>";
print "</html>FOOTER";
```

If you aren't already, you should use an editor with a syntax highlighter.  They point out issues like this clearly.

The reason the error was talking about a search pattern was because it was seeing a `/` character, which begins defining a regular expression (or search pattern).

Answer (score 7):

I think you're trying to do heredoc-style quoting, but it should look like this:

```
print <<FOOTER;
</body>
</html>
FOOTER
```

Saves you a lot of `print` statements ;) If you need variable interpolation, put the heredoc end token in double-quotes (`print <<"FOOTER";`). Single-quoting the token prevents interpolation (as pointed out by @daxim). For more information about heredoc
see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) or JFGI.

Comment: The unquoted form already interpolates. Your comment would make more sense if you would tell about the single-quoted identifier preventing interpolation. (It is [good style to always quote the identifier](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::ValuesAndExpressions::RequireQuotedHeredocTerminator).)

Answer (score 0):

You simply miss the print... Haven't you ?
You should finish your script with this :

```
print"<FOOTER />\n"; 
print"</body>";
print "</html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

What's this ?

```
</body>
print</html>FOOTER;
```

Probably this is where your error lie..