# Search pattern not terminated at filename.pl line 15

Tags: perl

[Search pattern not terminated in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299213/search-pattern-not-terminated-in-perl)
This link is not useful for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#FILE_HANDLE -> name used like that because of Bareword
#open file passed as argument
open FILE_HANDLE, "<", "$ARGV[0]" or die $!;

#reading file line by line
while (<FILE_HANDLE>)
{
    my $var = "Var";
    my $line = $_ if /\b$var\b/;
    #empty string check for $line
    if (length ($line // ''))
    {
        #spliting the string on the basis of space delimiter and stroing in array
        my @lineWords=split (' ', $line);
        my $signalname="$lineWords[2]";
        my $suffix="$lineWords[3]";
        my $compareWord='l:-1';
        my $i=3;
        while ($suffix ne $compareWord)
        {
            $i++;
            $signalname .= $suffix;
            $suffix="$lineWords[$i]";
        }
        $i += 3;
        print "$signalname $lineWords[$i]\n";
    }
}
close FILE_HANDLE;
```

In this perl script, I am getting following error :

> Search pattern not terminated at
>   CreateNameId.pl line
>   15.

This script worked well with some files but give above error for some files.

Comment: the line `if (length ($line // ''))`  is the Problem. What should it be?

Comment: @Jens this line is to skip empty line in file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script misses `use 5.010;` or `use Syntax::Construct '//';`. Your Perl version is probably too old and doesn't support the "defined-or" operator `//`.

The exact equivalent would be

```
if (length (defined($line) ? $line : ''))
```

Comment: Perl version -> 
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Comment: @UndefinedBehaviour: Perl v5.8.8 was released over eleven years ago. Time for an update perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a version of Perl earlier that v5.10 when the defined-or operator `//` was introduced, so Perl is treating `//` as an empty regex pattern

Instead of

```
if ( length ($line // '') ) { ... }
```

use

```
if ( $line =~ /\S/ ) { ... }
```

which also rejects lines consisting only of whitespace characters